# How to split integer number to individual character using java stream?

Tags: java

I am new to Java stream, I was trying to split integer like (12345) to individual value 1, 2, 3 ... and I did it like as bellow.

```
int number = 123456;
(number+"").chars()
    .mapToObj(e -> (char) e)
    .map(e -> Integer.parseInt(""+e))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

It works for me though but I am not sure, is it the correct way of doing it?

Comment: No need for 2 mappings: `Integer.toString(number).chars().map(n -> n - '0').forEach(System.out::println)`

Comment: As long as all you're doing is printing them, you don't need to convert the characters to integers. You could just print the characters.

Comment: thanks, Khelwood and Andreas.

Answer (score 1):

Without multiple cast and mappings :

```
Stream.of(String.valueOf(number).split("")).forEach(System.out::println);
```